# Car not starting from time to time

Tags: ford, starting, ignition, figo

Ford Figo 2012. Some mornings my car start 1st turn of the key. sometimes it will start after a couple of turns and the other day I had to get somebody to push it for me. Battery and alternator 100% and starter was tested for a full day. Had ignition problems in the past. This only happens first thing in the morning. What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This is going to be very hard to answer as there are a ton of things which could prevent it from starting. Do you have any extra dash lights when this happens? Does it not turn over (crank), or does it crank and not want to start (starter/engine goes around but it never starts)?

Comment: Sounds like a bad fuel pump relay to me. Had it fail on my car too and it made the fuel pump behave as follows: when starting a cold engine in the morning, i couldn't hear the pump buzzing when rotating the key in ignition position, and the engine then started only on the second start attempt. The rest of the day, the pump buzzed and the engine immediately started. I replaced the relay with a new one and solved the problem. By the way, i carefully cut the faulty relay (a Denso 156700-2480 one) open with a pocket knife and it didn't show any sign of internal damage or wear.